# How to write a script to publish my .NET Core Web App to Docker Hub?

Tags: visual-studio, docker

**What is Working:**
Presently I'm using Visual Studio to successfully publish my ASP.NET Core web apps to Docker hub.

**What I have tried that is NOT Working:** The "dotnet publish" command is not doing the same job -- probably because I'm not specifying my docker hub account... After looking at the documentation, I don't see how I can specify my docker hub account.

**What I want:** How can I write a script that does what the "publish" button does in visual studio (and publish to docker hub)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `docker login -u YourDockerHubName` command login.

Comment: Thanks -- I should have thought of that... However, I logged in (as suggested) and I tried the "dotnet publish" command again and then logged in to docker hub hoping to find a new image and... no new image... Maybe I need to add some more switches? "dotnet publish --help" did not list and obvious switches to try...

Comment: You can provide your Dockerfile or view [dotnet publish docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish)

Comment: Please clarify: are you suggesting I post my DockerFile here or specify my docker file with a command line switch for the "dotnet publish" command?